# Recommended way to store security token in gmail addon?

Tags: gmail-addons

While building gmail add-on, is there a recommended storage for storing secured tokens from a third party application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the
**PropertiesService**
service of the app-script to store the secured tokens.

**To set properties**

`PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('DAYS', '5');`

**To get properties**

`PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('DAYS');`

you can find more on
[google apps script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)